# ViewModel post back a null Collection in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

```c#
    public class SaleItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class SalesDBContext
    {
        public static List<SaleItem> GetItems()
        {
            var items = new List<SaleItem>(){
                new SaleItem{Id=1,Name="Soap"},
                new SaleItem{Id=2,Name="Milk Power"},
                new SaleItem{Id=3,Name="Toothpaste"},
                new SaleItem{Id=4,Name="Ice Cream"}
            };
            return items.ToList();
        }
    }

    public class SalesViewModel
    {
        public string Item { get; set; }
        public List<SaleItem> itemlist { get; set; }
    }
```

I have above `SalesViewModel` class and `SalesDBContext` for dummy data generation. I want to add items to a list selected from a dropdown. For that I have created the following view:

```html
@model MVCDropdown.Models.SalesViewModel
@using MVCDropdown.Models

<form method="post">
    <p>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Item, new SelectList(ViewBag.Items, "Id", "Name"), "--select--")
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </p>
    <p>
        @if (Model.itemlist != null)
        {
            <table>
                @foreach (var s in Model.itemlist)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@s.Name</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        }
    </p>
</form>
```

**The Controller**

```c#
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            SalesViewModel model = new SalesViewModel
            { 
                Item = "",
                itemlist = new List<SaleItem>()
            };
            PopDrodown();
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(SalesViewModel vm)
        {
            var t = SalesDBContext.GetItems().Where(x => x.Id == Convert.ToInt32(vm.Item)).FirstOrDefault();
            vm.itemlist.Add(t);
            PopDrodown();
            return View(vm);
        }

        private void PopDrodown()
        {
            ViewBag.Items = SalesDBContext.GetItems();
        }
```

Items added to the list should be displayed in a table under the dropdown.  However, when I post post back a selected item from the dropdown by pressing add, it returns a null `itemlist` to the controller, and previously added items are not there. How can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have a single input element inside your HTML form: that's the dropdown. So the only value that is sent to your controller action when the form is submitted is the `Item` property. If you want to send the collection you could use hidden fields:

```
<table>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.itemlist.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.itemlist[i].Id)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.itemlist[i].Name)
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.itemlist[i].Name)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Obviously if the user is not supposed to edit the values inside the HTML form, then a much better approach is to have a POST view model that will contain only the properties that the user can modify and you will retrieve the collection elements from the same place you retrieved them in the GET action.

Comment: It gives me a error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Did you keep the `@if (Model.itemlist != null)` check? On which line are you getting the NRE?

Comment: No it says the error is in the line `vm.itemlist.Add(t);` there i get a error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: I forgot to include a hidden field for `Id` and `Name` properties. Make sure that you have them both and that you have used a `for` loop as shown in my answer instead of a `foreach`.

Comment: I could avoid the error by adding `if (vm.itemlist == null) vm.itemlist = new List<SaleItem>();
            vm.itemlist.Add(t);`. But can you please tell me why i can't use foreach loop?

Comment: Because if you use a `foreach` loop, you are not generating correct `name` attributes of the hidden fields. You need to have the following in your markup: `<input type="hidden" name="itemlist[0].Id" value="1" />`, ... I invite you to read the following blog post: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/ to better familiarize yourself with the wire format that ASP.NET MVC model binder expects the incoming data to be in order to rehydrate your view model's collections.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is a great help.